# Display flex widgets styling interference by admin UI

Tags: css, flexbox, apostrophe-cms

I need some advise where the problem might be that a widget styling with `display: flex` displays it's content with *"line breaks"*.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75cm4fh9/2/).

The fiddle works. The two elements **text-div** and **background-div** are **next to each other**.

If I use the same in an *apostrophe widget* in an area the 2nd ordered is displayed **below** the 1st ordered.

I can't find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've the answer. Lunchtime. Sorry for your time.

I've put it in the wrong `<div>`.

Here is the *problem* to see: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75cm4fh9/3/)